# What does a Godel sentence actually look like?

Tags: logic, examples-counterexamples, incompleteness

My understanding is that Godel's first theorem says that there is a sentence that is in a sense true in a formal system F but cannot be derived in that system.

I then hear that Godel actually goes on to construct such a sentence.

My question is, what would this even look like?

For example, in Peano Arithmetic would it be something like:

5 + 3 * 15 ... = ...? Is it long? Is it short? Could it be written on a piece of paper?

If not what is wrong with my thinking?

Thanks

Comment: It is very very very long.  The sentence was not constructed, a (partial) **recipe** for constructing the sentence was given.  Since then some "natural" sentences have been constructed, not using the recipe.

Comment: See the following post for the construction of the Gödel sentence: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/34927/137499

Comment: Thanks for that, just how long is the actual formula though out of curiosity. My original question stands on whether it could be written on a piece of paper (however large). Another question is whether we know the first and/or last symbols in it

Comment: Someone on this site has tried to write it; see Hagen von Eitzen's answer to this [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/860603/has-the-g%c3%b6del-sentence-been-explicitly-produced).

Comment: For a brief exercise on "encoding", see this [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/817846/concrete-example-for-diagonal-lemma). If you perform the first steps in the arithmetization process, you can "taste" how it works ... and "measure" how far you have to go to produce an example of Gödel sentence.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Most sentences in the theory are longer than that.  In some sense, that sentence is very very very short, in a similar manner to how any given natural number you pick can get deemed "small".

Comment: "My question is, what would this even look like?"  Given that prime numbers don't have any sort of appearance or "look", it doesn't look like anything.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here's an explicit example, [due to Hagen von Eitzen](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/860627/28111) (I've made this answer community wiki so I don't get rep bonus for someone else's hard work):

¬∃b:∃c:∃d:〈∃e:∃f:∃g:〈a=((((((e+ f)+ g)· ((e+ f)+ g))· ((e+ f)+ g))+ ((e+ f)· (e+ f)))+ e) ∧ ∃h:∃i:〈〈∃j:h=(j· Si) ∧ 〈∃j:h=(d+ (j· S(i· Sg))) ∧ ∃j:(d+ j)=(i· Sg)〉〉 ∧ ∀j:〈∃k:S(j+ k)=g ⇒ ∀k:∀l:〈〈〈∃m:h=(k+ (m· S(i· Sj))) ∧ ∃m:(k+ m)=(i· Sj)〉 ∧ 〈∃m:e=(l+ (m· S(f· Sj))) ∧ ∃m:(l+ m)=(f· Sj)〉〉 ⇒ 〈〈¬l=SSSSSSSSSS0 ⇒ 〈〈∃m:h=S(k+ (m· S(i· SSj))) ∧ ∃m:S(k+ m)=(i· SSj)〉 ∧ 〈∃m:b=(l+ (m· S(c· Sj))) ∧ ∃m:(l+ m)=(c· Sj)〉〉〉 ∧ 〈l=SSSSSSSSSS0 ⇒ 〈〈〈∃m:h=S((a+ k)+ (m· S(i· SSj))) ∧ ∃m:S((a+ k)+ m)=(i· SSj)〉 ∧ 〈∃m:b=SSSSSSSSS(m· S(c· S(a+ k))) ∧ ∃m:SSSSSSSSSm=(c· S(a+ k))〉〉 ∧ ∀m:〈∃n:S(m+ n)=a ⇒ 〈∃n:b=SSSSSSSS(n· S(c· S(m+ k))) ∧ ∃n:SSSSSSSSn=(c· S(m+ k))〉〉〉〉〉〉〉〉〉 ∧ ∃e:∃f:∃g:∃h:∃i:〈〈〈〈〈∃j:i=(j· Sf) ∧ ∃j:i=(j· S(f· Sg))〉 ∧ ∀j:∀k:∀l:〈〈〈∃m:S(j+ m)=g ∧ 〈∃m:i=(k+ (m· S(f· Sj))) ∧ ∃m:(k+ m)=(f· Sj)〉〉 ∧ 〈∃m:i=(l+ (m· S(f· SSj))) ∧ ∃m:(l+ m)=(f· SSj)〉〉 ⇒ 〈k=l ∨ 〈∃m:e=(m· S(f· Sj)) ∧ 〈k=Sl ∨ l=Sk〉〉〉〉〉 ∧ ∀j:〈∃k:S(j+ k)=g ⇒ ∀k:∀l:∀m:∀n:〈〈〈〈〈∃o:e=(k+ (o· S(f· Sj))) ∧ ∃o:(k+ o)=(f· Sj)〉 ∧ 〈∃o:h=(l+ (o· S(f· Sj))) ∧ ∃o:(l+ o)=(f· Sj)〉〉 ∧ 〈∃o:h=(m+ (o· S(f· SSj))) ∧ ∃o:(m+ o)=(f· SSj)〉〉 ∧ 〈∃o:h=(n+ (o· S(f· SS(m+ j)))) ∧ ∃o:(n+ o)=(f· SS(m+ j))〉〉 ⇒ 〈〈〈〈〈〈∃o:((j+ l)+ o)=g ∧ 〈∃o:SSSSSSSSSo=k ⇒ l=S0〉〉 ∧ 〈〈〈k=0 ∨ k=SSSSSSS0〉 ∨ k=SSSSSSSS0〉 ⇒ l=Sm〉〉 ∧ 〈〈〈〈〈〈k=S0 ∨ k=SS0〉 ∨ k=SSS0〉 ∨ k=SSSS0〉 ∨ k=SSSSS0〉 ∨ k=SSSSSS0〉 ⇒ 〈l=S(m+ n) ∧ ∀o:〈〈∃p:〈∃q:S(p+ q)=m ∧ 〈∃q:e=(o+ (q· S(f· SS(j+ p)))) ∧ ∃q:(o+ q)=(f· SS(j+ p))〉〉 ∧ ∃p:〈∃q:S(p+ q)=n ∧ 〈∃q:e=(o+ (q· S(f· SS((m+ j)+ p)))) ∧ ∃q:(o+ q)=(f· SS((m+ j)+ p))〉〉〉 ⇒ 〈〈∀p:¬〈〈∃q:S(p+ q)=m ∧ 〈∃q:e=SSSSSS(q· S(f· SS(j+ p))) ∧ ∃q:SSSSSSq=(f· SS(j+ p))〉〉 ∧ 〈∃q:e=(o+ (q· S(f· SSS(j+ p)))) ∧ ∃q:(o+ q)=(f· SSS(j+ p))〉〉 ∨ ∀p:¬〈〈∃q:S(p+ q)=n ∧ 〈∃q:e=SSSSSS(q· S(f· SS((m+ j)+ p))) ∧ ∃q:SSSSSSq=(f· SS((m+ j)+ p))〉〉 ∧ 〈∃q:e=(o+ (q· S(f· SSS((m+ j)+ p)))) ∧ ∃q:(o+ q)=(f· SSS((m+ j)+ p))〉〉〉 ⇒ ∀p:¬〈〈∃q:S(p+ q)=(m+ n) ∧ 〈∃q:e=SSSSSS(q· S(f· SS(j+ p))) ∧ ∃q:SSSSSSq=(f· SS(j+ p))〉〉 ∧ 〈∃q:e=(o+ (q· S(f· SSS(j+ p)))) ∧ ∃q:(o+ q)=(f· SSS(j+ p))〉〉〉〉〉〉〉 ∧ ∀o:〈〈∃p:e=(o+ (p· S(f· SSj))) ∧ ∃p:(o+ p)=(f· SSj)〉 ⇒ 〈〈〈〈〈〈k=0 ∨ k=S0〉 ∨ k=SS0〉 ∨ k=SSSSSSS0〉 ⇒ 〈〈〈〈o=S0 ∨ o=SS0〉 ∨ o=SSS0〉 ∨ o=SSSSSS0〉 ∨ o=SSSSSSS0〉〉 ∧ 〈〈〈〈k=SSS0 ∨ k=SSSS0〉 ∨ k=SSSSS0〉 ∨ k=SSSSSSSS0〉 ⇒ 〈〈o=SSSS0 ∨ o=SSSSS0〉 ∨ ∃p:SSSSSSSSp=o〉〉〉 ∧ 〈k=SSSSSS0 ⇒ ∃p:SSSSSSSSSSp=o〉〉〉〉 ∧ ∀o:〈〈∃p:e=(o+ (p· S(f· SS(m+ j)))) ∧ ∃p:(o+ p)=(f· SS(m+ j))〉 ⇒ 〈〈〈k=0 ⇒ k=o〉 ∧ 〈〈〈k=S0 ∨ k=SS0〉 ∨ k=SSSSSS0〉 ⇒ 〈〈〈〈o=S0 ∨ o=SS0〉 ∨ o=SSS0〉 ∨ o=SSSSSS0〉 ∨ o=SSSSSSS0〉〉〉 ∧ 〈〈〈k=SSS0 ∨ k=SSSS0〉 ∨ k=SSSSS0〉 ⇒ 〈〈o=SSSS0 ∨ o=SSSSS0〉 ∨ ∃p:SSSSSSSSp=o〉〉〉〉〉 ∧ 〈j=0 ⇒ k=0〉〉〉〉〉 ∧ ∃j:〈〈〈g=S(j+ d) ∧ ∃k:e=(k· S(f· Sj))〉 ∧ ∀k:¬〈〈∃l:S(k+ l)=d ∧ 〈∃l:b=SSSSSS(l· S(c· Sk)) ∧ ∃l:SSSSSSl=(c· Sk)〉〉 ∧ ∃l:b=(l· S(c· SSk))〉〉 ∧ ∀k:∀l:〈〈∃m:S(k+ m)=d ∧ 〈∃m:b=(l+ (m· S(c· Sk))) ∧ ∃m:(l+ m)=(c· Sk)〉〉 ⇒ 〈∃m:e=(l+ (m· S(f· SS(j+ k)))) ∧ ∃m:(l+ m)=(f· SS(j+ k))〉〉〉〉 ∧ ∀j:∀k:〈〈∃l:e=(l· S(f· Sj)) ∧ 〈∃l:h=(k+ (l· S(f· SSj))) ∧ ∃l:(k+ l)=(f· SSj)〉〉 ⇒ 〈〈〈〈∃l:e=SSSSSS(l· S(f· SSj)) ∧ ∃l:SSSSSSl=(f· SSj)〉 ∧ 〈∃l:e=SSSSSSSSSS(l· S(f· SSSj)) ∧ ∃l:SSSSSSSSSSl=(f· SSSj)〉〉 ∧ 〈〈〈〈〈〈∃l:e=SSSSSSS(l· S(f· SSSSj)) ∧ ∃l:e=SSS(l· S(f· SSSSSj))〉 ∧ ∃l:e=SSSSSSSS(l· S(f· SSSSSSj))〉 ∧ ∃l:e=SSSSSSSSSS(l· S(f· SSSSSSSj))〉 ∧ ∃l:e=SSSSSSSSS(l· S(f· SSSSSSSSj))〉 ∨ 〈〈〈∃l:e=SSS(l· S(f· SSSSj)) ∧ ∃l:e=SSSSSSSSSS(l· S(f· SSSSSSj))〉 ∧ ∃l:e=SSSSSSSSS(l· S(f· SSSSSSSj))〉 ∧ 〈〈∃l:e=SSSS(l· S(f· SSSSSj)) ∧ ∃l:e=SSSSSSSSSS(l· S(f· SSSSSSSSj))〉 ∨ 〈∃l:e=SSSSS(l· S(f· SSSSSj)) ∧ ∃l:e=SSSSSSSSS(l· S(f· SSSSSSSSj))〉〉〉〉 ∨ 〈〈〈〈〈〈〈〈∃l:e=SSSSSS(l· S(f· SSSSj)) ∧ ∃l:e=SSSSSSSSSSS(l· S(f· SSSSSj))〉 ∧ ∃l:e=SSS(l· S(f· SSSSSSj))〉 ∧ ∃l:e=SSSSSSSSSS(l· S(f· SSSSSSSSj))〉 ∧ ∃l:e=SSSSSSSS(l· S(f· SSSSSSSSSj))〉 ∧ ∃l:e=SSSSSSSSSSS(l· S(f· SSSSSSSSSSj))〉 ∧ ∃l:e=SSSSSSSSSS(l· S(f· SSSSSSSSSSSSSj))〉 ∧ ∃l:e=SSSSSSSSSSS(l· S(f· SSSSSSSSSSSSSSj))〉 ∧ 〈〈〈∃l:e=SSSS(l· S(f· SSSSSSSj)) ∧ ∃l:e=SSSSSSSS(l· S(f· SSSSSSSSSSSj))〉 ∧ ∃l:e=SSSS(l· S(f· SSSSSSSSSSSSj))〉 ∨ 〈〈〈∃l:e=SSSSS(l· S(f· SSSSSSSj)) ∧ ∃l:e=SSSS(l· S(f· SSSSSSSSSSSj))〉 ∧ 〈∃l:e=SSSSS(l· S(f· SSSSSSSSSSSSj)) ∧ ∃l:SSSSSl=(f· SSSSSSSSSSSSj)〉〉 ∧ ∃l:e=SSSSSSSSSS(l· S(f· SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSj))〉〉〉〉〉 ∨ ∃l:∃m:〈〈〈〈∃n:S(l+ n)=j ∧ ∃n:e=(n· S(f· Sl))〉 ∧ 〈∃n:h=(m+ (n· S(f· SSl))) ∧ ∃n:(m+ n)=(f· SSl)〉〉 ∧ ∀n:∀o:∀p:〈〈〈〈∃q:i=(n+ (q· S(f· SSl))) ∧ ∃q:(n+ q)=(f· SSl)〉 ∧ ∃q:((l+ o)+ q)=j〉 ∧ 〈∃q:i=(p+ (q· S(f· SS(l+ o)))) ∧ ∃q:(p+ q)=(f· SS(l+ o))〉〉 ⇒ ∃q:(p+ q)=n〉〉 ∧ 〈〈〈〈〈〈〈〈〈〈〈∀n:∀o:〈〈∃p:S(n+ p)=m ∧ 〈∃p:e=(o+ (p· S(f· SS(n+ j)))) ∧ ∃p:(o+ p)=(f· SS(n+ j))〉〉 ⇒ ∃p:e=(o+ (p· S(f· SS(n+ l))))〉 ∨ 〈〈〈∃n:e=SSS(n· S(f· SSj)) ∧ ∃n:SSSn=(f· SSj)〉 ∧ k=m〉 ∧ ∃n:∃o:〈〈S(n+ o)=k ∧ ∀p:∀q:〈〈∃r:S(p+ r)=o ∧ 〈∃r:e=(q+ (r· S(f· SSS(p+ j)))) ∧ ∃r:(q+ r)=(f· SSS(p+ j))〉〉 ⇒ ∃r:e=(q+ (r· S(f· SSS(p+ (l+ n)))))〉〉 ∧ ∀p:∀q:〈〈∃r:S(p+ r)=n ∧ 〈∃r:e=(q+ (r· S(f· SSS(p+ (j+ o))))) ∧ ∃r:(q+ r)=(f· SSS(p+ (j+ o)))〉〉 ⇒ ∃r:e=(q+ (r· S(f· SSS(p+ l))))〉〉〉〉 ∨ 〈〈〈∃n:e=SSSSSSS(n· S(f· SSj)) ∧ ∃n:SSSSSSSn=(f· SSj)〉 ∧ k=SSm〉 ∧ ∀n:∀o:〈〈∃p:S(n+ p)=m ∧ 〈∃p:e=(o+ (p· S(f· SSSS(n+ j)))) ∧ ∃p:(o+ p)=(f· SSSS(n+ j))〉〉 ⇒ 〈∃p:e=(o+ (p· S(f· SS(n+ l)))) ∧ ∃p:(o+ p)=(f· SS(n+ l))〉〉〉〉 ∨ 〈〈〈∃n:e=SSSSSSS(n· S(f· SSl)) ∧ ∃n:SSSSSSSn=(f· SSl)〉 ∧ m=SSk〉 ∧ ∀n:∀o:〈〈∃p:S(n+ p)=k ∧ 〈∃p:e=(o+ (p· S(f· SSSS(n+ l)))) ∧ ∃p:(o+ p)=(f· SSSS(n+ l))〉〉 ⇒ 〈∃p:e=(o+ (p· S(f· SS(n+ j)))) ∧ ∃p:(o+ p)=(f· SS(n+ j))〉〉〉〉 ∨ ∃n:∃o:〈〈〈〈〈〈∃p:h=(n+ (p· S(f· SSSl))) ∧ ∃p:(n+ p)=(f· SSSl)〉 ∧ S(n+ o)=m〉 ∧ 〈∃p:e=SSSSSSSS(p· S(f· SSSj)) ∧ ∃p:SSSSSSSSp=(f· SSSj)〉〉 ∧ 〈∃p:e=SSSSSSSS(p· S(f· SSSS(j+ n))) ∧ ∃p:SSSSSSSSp=(f· SSSS(j+ n))〉〉 ∧ ∀p:∀q:〈〈∃r:S(p+ r)=n ∧ 〈∃r:e=(q+ (r· S(f· SSSS(p+ j)))) ∧ ∃r:(q+ r)=(f· SSSS(p+ j))〉〉 ⇒ 〈∃r:e=(q+ (r· S(f· SSS(p+ l)))) ∧ ∃r:(q+ r)=(f· SSS(p+ l))〉〉〉 ∧ ∀p:∀q:〈〈∃r:S(p+ r)=o ∧ 〈∃r:e=(q+ (r· S(f· SSSSS(p+ (j+ n))))) ∧ ∃r:(q+ r)=(f· SSSSS(p+ (j+ n)))〉〉 ⇒ 〈∃r:e=(q+ (r· S(f· SSS(p+ (l+ n))))) ∧ ∃r:(q+ r)=(f· SSS(p+ (l+ n)))〉〉〉〉 ∨ ∃n:∃o:〈〈〈〈〈〈∃p:h=(n+ (p· S(f· SSSj))) ∧ ∃p:(n+ p)=(f· SSSj)〉 ∧ S(n+ o)=k〉 ∧ 〈∃p:e=SSSSSSSS(p· S(f· SSSl)) ∧ ∃p:SSSSSSSSp=(f· SSSl)〉〉 ∧ 〈∃p:e=SSSSSSSS(p· S(f· SSSS(l+ n))) ∧ ∃p:SSSSSSSSp=(f· SSSS(l+ n))〉〉 ∧ ∀p:∀q:〈〈∃r:S(p+ r)=n ∧ 〈∃r:e=(q+ (r· S(f· SSSS(p+ l)))) ∧ ∃r:(q+ r)=(f· SSSS(p+ l))〉〉 ⇒ 〈∃r:e=(q+ (r· S(f· SSS(p+ j)))) ∧ ∃r:(q+ r)=(f· SSS(p+ j))〉〉〉 ∧ ∀p:∀q:〈〈∃r:S(p+ r)=o ∧ 〈∃r:e=(q+ (r· S(f· SSSSS(p+ (l+ n))))) ∧ ∃r:(q+ r)=(f· SSSSS(p+ (l+ n)))〉〉 ⇒ 〈∃r:e=(q+ (r· S(f· SSS(p+ (j+ n))))) ∧ ∃r:(q+ r)=(f· SSS(p+ (j+ n)))〉〉〉〉 ∨ 〈〈∃n:e=SS(n· S(f· SSl)) ∧ ∃n:SSn=(f· SSl)〉 ∧ ∀n:∀o:〈〈∃p:S(n+ p)=k ∧ 〈∃p:e=(o+ (p· S(f· SS(n+ j)))) ∧ ∃p:(o+ p)=(f· SS(n+ j))〉〉 ⇒ ∃p:e=(o+ (p· S(f· SSS(n+ l))))〉〉〉 ∨ ∃n:〈〈〈∃o:h=(n+ (o· S(f· SSSl))) ∧ ∃o:(n+ o)=(f· SSSl)〉 ∧ 〈∃o:e=SS(o· S(f· SSl)) ∧ ∃o:SSo=(f· SSl)〉〉 ∧ ∀o:∀p:〈〈∃q:S(o+ q)=k ∧ 〈∃q:e=(p+ (q· S(f· SS(o+ j)))) ∧ ∃q:(p+ q)=(f· SS(o+ j))〉〉 ⇒ ∃q:e=(p+ (q· S(f· SSS(o+ (l+ n)))))〉〉〉 ∨ 〈k=SSm ∧ ∃n:∃o:〈〈〈〈S(n+ o)=m ∧ 〈∃p:e=S(p· S(f· SSj)) ∧ ∃p:Sp=(f· SSj)〉〉 ∧ 〈∃p:e=S(p· S(f· SSl)) ∧ ∃p:Sp=(f· SSl)〉〉 ∧ ∀p:∀q:〈〈∃r:S(p+ r)=o ∧ 〈∃r:e=(q+ (r· S(f· SSSSS(p+ (j+ n))))) ∧ ∃r:(q+ r)=(f· SSSSS(p+ (j+ n)))〉〉 ⇒ ∃r:e=(q+ (r· S(f· SSS(p+ l))))〉〉 ∧ ∀p:∀q:〈〈∃r:S(p+ r)=n ∧ 〈∃r:e=(q+ (r· S(f· SSSS(p+ j)))) ∧ ∃r:(q+ r)=(f· SSSS(p+ j))〉〉 ⇒ ∃r:e=(q+ (r· S(f· SSS(p+ (l+ o)))))〉〉〉〉 ∨ ∃n:∃o:∃p:∃q:〈〈〈m=SSq ∧ 〈∃r:e=SSSSSS(r· S(f· SSl)) ∧ ∃r:SSSSSSr=(f· SSl)〉〉 ∧ 〈∃r:e=(n+ (r· S(f· SSSl))) ∧ ∃r:(n+ r)=(f· SSSl)〉〉 ∧ 〈∀r:〈∃s:〈∃t:S(s+ t)=p ∧ 〈∃t:e=(r+ (t· S(f· S(o+ s)))) ∧ ∃t:(r+ t)=(f· S(o+ s))〉〉 ⇒ ∀s:¬〈〈∃t:S(s+ t)=q ∧ 〈∃t:e=SSSSSS(t· S(f· SSSS(l+ s))) ∧ ∃t:SSSSSSt=(f· SSSS(l+ s))〉〉 ∧ 〈∃t:e=(r+ (t· S(f· SSSSS(l+ s)))) ∧ ∃t:(r+ t)=(f· SSSSS(l+ s))〉〉〉 ∧ ∃r:∃s:〈〈∃t:r=(t· Ss) ∧ 〈∃t:r=(k+ (t· S(s· Sq))) ∧ ∃t:(k+ t)=(s· Sq)〉〉 ∧ ∀t:∀u:∀v:∀w:〈〈〈〈∃x:S(t+ x)=q ∧ 〈∃x:r=(u+ (x· S(s· St))) ∧ ∃x:(u+ x)=(s· St)〉〉 ∧ 〈∃x:r=(v+ (x· S(s· SSt))) ∧ ∃x:(v+ x)=(s· SSt)〉〉 ∧ 〈∃x:e=(w+ (x· S(f· SSSS(l+ t)))) ∧ ∃x:(w+ x)=(f· SSSS(l+ t))〉〉 ⇒ 〈〈¬w=n ⇒ 〈〈∃x:e=(w+ (x· S(f· SS(j+ u)))) ∧ ∃x:(w+ x)=(f· SS(j+ u))〉 ∧ v=Su〉〉 ∧ 〈w=n ⇒ 〈∀x:∀y:〈〈∃z:S(x+ z)=p ∧ 〈∃z:e=(y+ (z· S(f· S(o+ x)))) ∧ ∃z:(y+ z)=(f· S(o+ x))〉〉 ⇒ 〈∃z:e=(y+ (z· S(f· SS((x+ u)+ j)))) ∧ ∃z:(y+ z)=(f· SS((x+ u)+ j))〉〉 ∧ v=(p+ u)〉〉〉〉〉〉〉〉 ∨ ∃n:〈∀o:〈〈〈∃p:S(o+ p)=j ∧ ∃p:e=(p· S(f· So))〉 ∧ ∀p:∀q:∀r:〈〈〈〈∃s:i=(q+ (s· S(f· So))) ∧ ∃s:(q+ s)=(f· So)〉 ∧ 〈∃s:i=(r+ (s· S(f· SS(p+ o)))) ∧ ∃s:(r+ s)=(f· SS(p+ o))〉〉 ∧ ∃s:S((o+ p)+ s)=j〉 ⇒ ∃s:S(q+ s)=r〉〉 ⇒ ∀p:¬〈〈〈∃q:h=(p+ (q· S(f· So))) ∧ ∃q:(p+ q)=(f· So)〉 ∧ ∃q:〈∃r:S(q+ r)=p ∧ 〈∃r:e=(n+ (r· S(f· S(o+ q)))) ∧ ∃r:(n+ r)=(f· S(o+ q))〉〉〉 ∧ ∀q:¬〈〈∃r:S(q+ r)=p ∧ 〈∃r:e=SSSSSS(r· S(f· S(o+ q))) ∧ ∃r:SSSSSSr=(f· S(o+ q))〉〉 ∧ 〈∃r:e=(n+ (r· S(f· SS(o+ q)))) ∧ ∃r:(n+ r)=(f· SS(o+ q))〉〉〉〉 ∧ 〈〈〈∃o:e=SSSSSS(o· S(f· SSj)) ∧ ∃o:SSSSSSo=(f· SSj)〉 ∧ 〈∃o:e=(n+ (o· S(f· SSSj))) ∧ ∃o:(n+ o)=(f· SSSj)〉〉 ∧ ∀o:∀p:〈〈∃q:S(o+ q)=m ∧ 〈∃q:e=(p+ (q· S(f· SSSS(o+ j)))) ∧ ∃q:(p+ q)=(f· SSSS(o+ j))〉〉 ⇒ 〈∃q:e=(p+ (q· S(f· SS(o+ l)))) ∧ ∃q:(p+ q)=(f· SS(o+ l))〉〉〉〉〉 ∨ ∃n:∃o:〈〈〈〈∃p:S(n+ p)=j ∧ ∃p:e=(p· S(f· Sn))〉 ∧ 〈∃p:h=(o+ (p· S(f· SSn))) ∧ ∃p:(o+ p)=(f· SSn)〉〉 ∧ ∀p:∀q:∀r:〈〈〈〈∃s:i=(p+ (s· S(f· SSn))) ∧ ∃s:(p+ s)=(f· SSn)〉 ∧ ∃s:((n+ q)+ s)=j〉 ∧ 〈∃s:i=(r+ (s· S(f· SS(n+ q)))) ∧ ∃s:(r+ s)=(f· SS(n+ q))〉〉 ⇒ ∃s:(r+ s)=p〉〉 ∧ 〈〈〈〈〈〈〈∃p:e=SS(p· S(f· SSj)) ∧ ∃p:SSp=(f· SSj)〉 ∧ ∀p:∀q:〈〈∃r:S(p+ r)=m ∧ 〈∃r:e=(q+ (r· S(f· SSS(p+ j)))) ∧ ∃r:(q+ r)=(f· SSS(p+ j))〉〉 ⇒ ∃r:e=(q+ (r· S(f· SS(p+ l))))〉〉 ∧ ∀p:∀q:〈〈∃r:S(p+ r)=o ∧ 〈∃r:e=(q+ (r· S(f· SSS(p+ (j+ m))))) ∧ ∃r:(q+ r)=(f· SSS(p+ (j+ m)))〉〉 ⇒ ∃r:e=(q+ (r· S(f· SS(p+ n))))〉〉 ∨ 〈〈〈∃p:e=S(p· S(f· SSl)) ∧ ∃p:Sp=(f· SSl)〉 ∧ ∀p:∀q:〈〈∃r:S(p+ r)=o ∧ 〈∃r:e=(q+ (r· S(f· SSS(p+ l)))) ∧ ∃r:(q+ r)=(f· SSS(p+ l))〉〉 ⇒ 〈∃r:e=(q+ (r· S(f· SS(p+ n)))) ∧ ∃r:(q+ r)=(f· SS(p+ n))〉〉〉 ∧ ∀p:∀q:〈〈∃r:S(p+ r)=k ∧ 〈∃r:e=(q+ (r· S(f· SS(p+ j)))) ∧ ∃r:(q+ r)=(f· SS(p+ j))〉〉 ⇒ 〈∃r:e=(q+ (r· S(f· SSS(p+ (l+ o))))) ∧ ∃r:(q+ r)=(f· SSS(p+ (l+ o)))〉〉〉〉 ∨ 〈〈∃p:e=SSS(p· S(f· SSj)) ∧ ∃p:SSSp=(f· SSj)〉 ∧ ∃p:∃q:∃r:〈〈〈〈〈S(p+ q)=k ∧ S(p+ r)=m〉 ∧ S(r+ q)=o〉 ∧ ∀s:∀t:〈〈∃u:S(s+ u)=p ∧ 〈∃u:e=(t+ (u· S(f· SSS(s+ j)))) ∧ ∃u:(t+ u)=(f· SSS(s+ j))〉〉 ⇒ ∃u:e=(t+ (u· S(f· SSS(s+ l))))〉〉 ∧ ∀s:∀t:〈〈∃u:S(s+ u)=r ∧ 〈∃u:e=(t+ (u· S(f· SSS(s+ n)))) ∧ ∃u:(t+ u)=(f· SSS(s+ n))〉〉 ⇒ 〈∃u:e=(t+ (u· S(f· SSS(s+ (l+ p))))) ∧ ∃u:(t+ u)=(f· SSS(s+ (l+ p)))〉〉〉 ∧ ∀s:∀t:〈〈∃u:S(s+ u)=q ∧ 〈∃u:e=(t+ (u· S(f· SSS(s+ (j+ p))))) ∧ ∃u:(t+ u)=(f· SSS(s+ (j+ p)))〉〉 ⇒ ∃u:e=(t+ (u· S(f· SSS(s+ (n+ r)))))〉〉〉〉 ∨ ∃p:〈〈〈〈〈〈〈〈∃q:e=SSSSSS(q· S(f· SSj)) ∧ ∃q:SSSSSSq=(f· SSj)〉 ∧ 〈∃q:e=(p+ (q· S(f· SSSj))) ∧ ∃q:(p+ q)=(f· SSSj)〉〉 ∧ 〈∃q:e=SSSSSS(q· S(f· SSn)) ∧ ∃q:SSSSSSq=(f· SSn)〉〉 ∧ 〈∃q:e=(p+ (q· S(f· SSSn))) ∧ ∃q:(p+ q)=(f· SSSn)〉〉 ∧ 〈∃q:e=S(q· S(f· SSSSn)) ∧ ∃q:Sq=(f· SSSSn)〉〉 ∧ ∀q:∀r:〈〈∃s:S(q+ s)=m ∧ 〈∃s:e=(r+ (s· S(f· SSSS(q+ j)))) ∧ ∃s:(r+ s)=(f· SSSS(q+ j))〉〉 ⇒ 〈∃s:e=(r+ (s· S(f· SSSSS(q+ n)))) ∧ ∃s:(r+ s)=(f· SSSSS(q+ n))〉〉〉 ∧ ∀q:∀r:∀s:〈〈〈∃t:S(q+ t)=m ∧ 〈∃t:e=(r+ (t· S(f· SS(l+ q)))) ∧ ∃t:(r+ t)=(f· SS(l+ q))〉〉 ∧ 〈∃t:e=(s+ (t· S(f· SSSS(j+ q)))) ∧ ∃t:(s+ t)=(f· SSSS(j+ q))〉〉 ⇒ 〈〈s=p ⇒ r=SSSSSSSSS0〉 ∧ 〈¬s=p ⇒ r=s〉〉〉〉 ∧ ∃q:∃r:〈〈∃s:q=SSSS((m+ l)+ (s· S(r· SSSSj))) ∧ ∃s:SSSS((m+ l)+ s)=(r· SSSSj)〉 ∧ ∀s:∀t:∀u:∀v:∀w:〈〈〈〈〈∃x:S(s+ x)=m ∧ 〈∃x:q=(t+ (x· S(r· SSSS(j+ s)))) ∧ ∃x:(t+ x)=(r· SSSS(j+ s))〉〉 ∧ 〈∃x:q=(u+ (x· S(r· SSSSS(j+ s)))) ∧ ∃x:(u+ x)=(r· SSSSS(j+ s))〉〉 ∧ 〈∃x:e=(v+ (x· S(f· SSSS(j+ s)))) ∧ ∃x:(v+ x)=(f· SSSS(j+ s))〉〉 ∧ 〈∃x:e=(w+ (x· S(f· St))) ∧ ∃x:(w+ x)=(f· St)〉〉 ⇒ 〈〈v=p ⇒ 〈〈u=SSt ∧ 〈∃x:e=(p+ (x· S(f· SSt))) ∧ ∃x:(p+ x)=(f· SSt)〉〉 ∧ w=SSSSSSSS0〉〉 ∧ 〈¬v=p ⇒ 〈u=St ∧ w=v〉〉〉〉〉〉〉 ∨ 〈∃p:〈〈〈S(n+ o)=j ∧ 〈∃q:i=(p+ (q· S(f· Sl))) ∧ ∃q:(p+ q)=(f· Sl)〉〉 ∧ 〈∃q:i=(p+ (q· S(f· SSj))) ∧ ∃q:(p+ q)=(f· SSj)〉〉 ∧ ∀q:∀r:〈〈∃s:S((l+ q)+ s)=j ∧ 〈∃s:i=(r+ (s· S(f· SS(l+ q)))) ∧ ∃s:(r+ s)=(f· SS(l+ q))〉〉 ⇒ ∃s:S(p+ s)=r〉〉 ∧ 〈〈〈∃p:e=S(p· S(f· SSj)) ∧ ∃p:Sp=(f· SSj)〉 ∧ ∀p:∀q:〈〈∃r:S(p+ r)=m ∧ 〈∃r:e=(q+ (r· S(f· SSS(p+ j)))) ∧ ∃r:(q+ r)=(f· SSS(p+ j))〉〉 ⇒ 〈∃r:e=(q+ (r· S(f· SS(p+ l)))) ∧ ∃r:(q+ r)=(f· SS(p+ l))〉〉〉 ∧ ∀p:∀q:〈〈∃r:S(p+ r)=o ∧ 〈∃r:e=(q+ (r· S(f· SS(p+ n)))) ∧ ∃r:(q+ r)=(f· SS(p+ n))〉〉 ⇒ 〈∃r:e=(q+ (r· S(f· SSS(p+ (j+ m))))) ∧ ∃r:(q+ r)=(f· SSS(p+ (j+ m)))〉〉〉〉〉〉〉〉〉〉〉〉

Comment: Hm... While dazzling, it would be great if someone could unpack this (preferably in English -- I struggle with mathematical German which is the language Hagen writes in).

Comment: Somehow I think that the previous comment misses the point entirely.