# Gödel's theorems and nonstandard model of $PA$

Tags: logic, incompleteness

According to the Second incompleteness theorem $Con(PA)$ is independent of $PA$. So if $PA$ is consistent $PA + \neg Con(PA)$ is also consistent which means that there exist a number $t$ which codes a proof of $1=0$. But $t$ isn't a "regular" natural number because $PA + \neg Con(PA)$ is a nonstandard model of $PA$.

My question is, how do we know that the Gödel's sentence of $PA + \neg Con(PA)$ exists (its code is a "regular" natural number)?

Comment: We don't know if $Con(PA)$ is independent of $PA$. Second incompleteness theorem only guarantees that $Con(PA)$ is not provable from $PA$ ($\neg Con(PA)$ might still be provable), which isn't quite what "independent" means.

Comment: Because one has been explicitly constructed, or at least a precise recipe for constructing it has been given. {Except that the word "it" hides some complications.)

Comment: (Sorry, the downvote was mine - I misclicked.)

Comment: @Wojowu How could PA prove $\neg$ Con(PA)? In the standard model, Con(PA) is true so PA cannot prove its negation. Sorry if I misunderstood your remark.

Comment: @hot_queen It might be the case that only nonstandard models of arithmetic exist.

Comment: @Wojowu Can you elaborate? Isn't it clear that $(\omega, +, .)$ models  PA?

Comment: @hot_queen I have just now realized that if PA proves $\neg Con(PA)$, then ZFC would necessarily be inconsistent, so if you believe ZFC is consistent, then indeed what I say is incorrect :P

Comment: @Wojowu Doesn't it say more? Suppose PA proves $\neg$ Con(PA). Then we can search for a witness in the standard model and decode it to a standard proof of $0 = 1$ implying that PA is inconsistent.

Comment: @hot_queen Your argument is sound on the grounds of ZFC, where you can prove existence of the standard model. So in ZFC, you can actually prove that $PA$ does _not_ prove $\neg Con(PA)$. However, the same cannot be shown on the grounds on $PA$ itself. i.e. there is a (necessarily nonstandard) model of $PA$ in which "$PA$ proves $\neg Con(PA)$".

Comment: @Wojowu I wasn't working in a a formal system but I guess I now understand what you mean: Working in PA + Con(PA) we cannot prove Con(PA + Con(PA)).

Comment: @hot_queen Yes, that's essentially it.

Answer (score 3):

I think there's a bit of confusion here.

First, "$PA+\neg Con(PA)$ is a nonstandard model of $PA$" is false. "$PA+\neg Con(PA)$" is a set of sentences. It can be true, or false, in nonstandard models, but it is not a model itself.

As to how we know the sentence "$\neg Con(PA)$" (which is the only weird sentence in $PA+\neg Con(PA)$) exists: we can actually explicitly write it down! Godel's original paper gives a recipe for how to do this. Actually carrying the recipe out all the way is lengthy, but has been done - see e.g. [What does a Godel sentence actually look like?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1472769/what-does-a-godel-sentence-actually-look-like). And there are much more efficient ways to do it, too.

---

EDIT: Just to be clear, that example Godel sentence is **NOT MINE** - it was constructed by Hagen von Eitzen.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1472769/what-does-a-godel-sentence-actually-look-like/1484929#1484929 is quite beautiful, in a monstrous way.

Comment: @BrianO I know, right?

Answer (score 2):

The construction of the Gödel for *any* theory that includes PA depends *only* on *what the axioms of that theory are*, textually. It does not depend on having a particular model of the theory, or what the properties of that model is, but proceeds entirely *in the metatheory*, where we assumes the integers are just the standard ones.

This holds in particular for  $\mathrm{PA}+\neg\mathit{Con}(\mathrm{PA})$.