# Godel's incompleteness theorem still holds if truth values of all self-referential sentences become indeterminate?

Tags: logic

Godel's incompleteness theorem is proved by showing that a formula G with Gödel number g which says: ‘the formula with Gödel number g is not demonstrable’ is true but not provable. However, considering the similar liar paradox : a formula G with Gödel number g which says: ‘the formula with Gödel number g is not true’. Then this liar paradox certainly could neither be true or false. And we know that many paradoxes arise because of self-reference (such as Russell's paradox and Berry paradox). Thus it seems reasonable to make the truth value of all self-referential sentences to be indeterminate. My question is would it be possible to have a complete (and strong enough) logic system if we exclude all these self-referential sentences?

Comment: I am not aware of a proof of Goedel's results that does not somehow use self-reference. Same for the halting problem.

Comment: The gist of [Gödel’s Incompleteness Theorems](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel-incompleteness/) is that - for certain formal systems satisfying certain assumptions - there is an *undecidable* statement. Following the original result, [other examples of arithmetical" undecidable statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris%E2%80%93Harrington_theorem) has been found. The proof un the undecidability of these ones does not involve self-referentiality.

Comment: "self-referential sentences" are not *per se* part of the formal system; we consider the formal system of e.g. arithmetic and we use the features of natural numbers to "manage" facts about the formal system itself, like being a formula, a derivation, etc.

Comment: Only at the end of the process, when we have proved the GIT, we are left with a sentence $G$, fully compliant with the syntactical specifications of the language such that the rule of logic (first-order predicate calculus) with the axioms of the system (e.g. first-order version of Peano axioms for arithmetic), such that neither %G% nor its negation $\lnot G$ are derivable in the system.

Comment: But our "natural expectation" about the axioms of arithmetic and their formal counterpart is that they express "true fact" about the intuitive domain of natural numbers. Thus, having found and undecidable $G$ as above, we are prone to say that - being a statement in the language of formal arithmetic - it express a fact about numbers, and thus either it express a TRUE fact about numbers, or it express a FALSE fact about them. Conclusion (according to the above line of thought): one of $G$ and $\lnot G$ is TRUE about numbers, but neither of them is provable.

Comment: Second conclusion: strictly speaking, *self-referentiality* is not the key feature of GIT result.

Comment: Regarding possible approaches self-referential sentences (and others) considered as indeterminate, see e.g [Vagueness](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/vagueness/#ManValLog) and [Liar Paradox](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/liar-paradox/).

Comment: Okay, I see that the Godel's sentence could indeed be turned into a sentence about arithmetic, but is there any specific example of this arithmetic statement? If we follow the construction of the godel's sentence, we should be able to obtain a explicit statement about arithmetic; however, I haven't seen any arithmetic statement that is true but couldn't be proved.

Comment: @Richard See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1472769/what-does-a-godel-sentence-actually-look-like/1484929#1484929. Also note that by the (proof of the) MRDP theorem, we can even make do with a *Diophantine equation* (relatedly, see Jones' paper [*Universal Diophantine equation*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2273588#metadata_info_tab_contents)). Finally, if you're looking for a *natural* example of an arithmetic sentence not provable in first-order Peano arithmetic, google "Paris-Harrington theorem."

Comment: "I see that the Godel's sentence could indeed be turned into a sentence about arithmetic" No, the Godel sentence **is** a sentence about (indeed, literally in the language of) arithmetic. The natural-language-ish expression "I am not (PA-)provable" is an informal gloss after the fact, or a blueprint for finding it it, but it is not the sentence itself. This may seem like hair-splitting, but it's crucially important.

Comment: @Richard You have it backwards. The Godel sentence *is* a sentence about arithmetic that *could be* viewed as asserting its own unprovability. And it’s not that it can’t be proved (otherwise how would we know it’s true?), it’s that it can’t be proved in PA. There are more natural examples of true arithmetic statements  not provable in PA, e.g. Goodstein’s theorem

Comment: @Noah seems you beat me.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I'm everywhere! I'm everywhere!

Comment: See the [SEP article "Self-Reference"][1] for some discussion of approaches to the paradoxes of self-reference that involve logics with an indeterminate truth value.


  [1]: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/self-reference/

Comment: Thanks for your guys' corrections and examples. I will check the references you gave.